# Apply only coupon or discount

Tags: 7, commerce

I have a task. Will try to describe.
For example, there is Order discount = 25%.
I go to checkout step.
I'm able also to add coupon here.
Coupons provides 30% (for example).
The task is:
If coupons discount is greater then order discount, we should apply only coupon's discount and remove order discount.
If order discount is greater then coupon's discount, we should keep order discount and don't apply coupon.
So, the goal is to apply the biggest discount only.
How can achive it?

I have tried to do it using Rules module - no luck.

Any help appreciated